# jQuery Form Plugin: IE problems with ajaxForm()

Tags: jquery, jquery-forms-plugin

I'm uploading files without problems using this plugin in every browser except IE. The error is the following:

Line: 483
Error: Access is denied.

(the jquery form plugin file is:
 * jQuery Form Plugin
 * version: 3.27.0-2013.02.06
)

Any ideas?

Comment: which ie ? does your plugin is supposed to support ie ?

Answer (score 0):

It security problem resulted in the fact that I was dynamically adding input:files to the form. Making the input part of the original html solved the problem